# 彼はお金を残らず奪われた。— が instead of を

Tags: particle-が, particle-を

Shouldn't が be used instead of を since 残る is an intransitive verb?

Comment: Do you understand indirect passive sentences such as 彼は泥棒に財布を盗まれた?

Answer (score 2):

> 彼はお金を残らず奪われた。

お金{かね}を is connected here with 奪われた{うばわれた}, passive past form of transitive verb 奪う{うばう} "to steal, to seize".

残らず{のこらず} is adverbial modifier of 奪われた{うばわれた}, it means "without remaining".